# Send to printer a specific document layout from code

Tags: java, layout, printing, png

i need to print on paper some png files below their filename as text, in java.
The doc style should follow this example:

[image]

How can i achive this?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I have found this nice "IText" guide, and seems exactly what i was looking for.
It's just for creating pdf, so it won't sent nothing to the printer, but can resolve my problem in a nice way. I'll give it a try tomorrow
[IText Guide](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/index.html)

Comment: I would try creating this template through HTML, and then sending that html page to the printer. That way you can use HTML for the images and css for the layout.

Comment: Start here: [The Java™ Tutorials - Lesson: Printing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/)